# Read default browser's cookie in Android

Tags: android

I am building an App which can be downloaded from my web server using the default browser. While the user is getting to download the App, I am actually creating a cookie and saving it on their device.

For some reason, I need to read the cookie which I did set for them after they install the App at first launch only.

As such, I need a way to read the value of the browser's cookie which I did set for them before when they were installing the App from my server.

I don't mind putting a hidden Web View if it helps with the issue.

So to recap it all, I need a way in my App to read the value of a specific cookie which was set in the default browser (given I have the cookie name and the website URL).

Please advice...

Answer (score 3):

> I need a way in my App to read the value of a specific cookie which was set in the default browser (given I have the cookie name and the website URL)

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Apps cannot read cookies out of browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Anyway do you have any alternative ideas to making this scenario actually work?

Comment: @WassimTaher: Considering that I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish, I cannot really answer that. If the user is logging into the site to download the APK, have them log back in via the app to connect the app to the user.